# Is the Disney series of Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes canon to Avengers timeline?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, canon, avengers-earth-mightiest-heroes

Is the Disney animated series of ***The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes*** canon to the whole series?

Comment: Which series are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are currently no animated shows that are part of the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Marvel identifies the majority of their thousands of canon universes by giving them an "universe number". These are referred to occasionally in the *Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe*, and the Jeff Christiansen (the most recent author of those books) keeps an Appendix which includes [all of the numbered universes](http://www.marvunapp.com/master/earthteaz.htm). So, it's usually pretty simple to figure out if two movies or TV shows or comic books take place in the same canon.

The Marvel Cinematic Universe is [**Earth-199999**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-199999), and includes all movies produced directly by Marvel Studios (starting with *Iron Man*), plus the live-action ABC shows (two, so far) and the live-action Netflix shows (three, so far). It will presumably include any future live-action movies or TV shows that fall into those categories, but no animated shows yet.

The animated TV show 
*Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes* takes place in [**Earth-8096**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-8096), which also included *Wolverine and the X-Men* plus two animated made-for-TV movies (a Hulk movie and a Thor movie).

After *Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes* was cancelled, Marvel replaced it with *Avengers Assemble*. That show takes place in [**Earth-12041**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Earth-12041), which is the shared universe for all of Marvel's animated shows currently airing on Disney's network, plus the cancelled *Hulk and the Agents of SMASH*. While those shows are generally written to have the same "tone" as the MCU movies, and have similar storylines and even some chartacter background, they are different canon universes.

Comment: This is not quite right. The MCU movies are not beholden to any continuity generated by the recent live-action TV shows, so I would say there is a TV universe (MTU?) separate from the MCU.

Comment: You can say that they're different, but Marvel does not. They clearly and definitively place their TV shows in the same canon universe as the movies. They choose to make the connection one way only (movie --> TV) but they are all Earth-199999.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

*The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes* is not canon to the Marvel Cinematic Universe. You can refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) or tag a wiki of [Marvel Cinematic Universe tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/marvel-cinematic-universe/info) to know what is canon and what not.

Until now there is no animated show canon to Marvel Cinematic Universe. Even [*Guardians of the Galaxy* (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_(TV_series)) is also not canon, even when it's a continuation of the Guardians of the Galaxy film.

Anyway, it's also been clear from the team members too, as Ant-Man/Giant-Man, Iron Man, the Hulk, Wasp and Thor are the founding members of The Avengers: Earth's Mightiest Heroes, but in MCU Hank Pym is not part of the Avengers and Scott Lang didn't joined the Avengers team until now. And we have only been shown the Wasp costume in the end credits of the Ant-man film.

Comment: True, but the second part of the answer is made of in-universe reason why both shows cannot possibly be in the same continuity. +1 for that.

Comment: @Richard That’s why the second part of the question and MCU heads don't have to confirm about each and every show being canon or not. As this one was clearly not. Maybe you can find novelization of it too, as the other answer also used wikia link and which are also not 100% reliable.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - The problem with a wiki is that I (or indeed anyone, regardless of their ignorance of the subject at hand) can change it so that it says pretty much anything. You're not wrong that it's not part of the MCU, but a quality answer would back it up.

Comment: @Richard Obviously i know how wikipedia work and how other wikia site too, anyway. Wikipedia don't accept unsourced material but we can't be 100% relied on there sources too. That's why i did backed up by explaining about the Ant-man appearance as comparison for both universe, as same character appeared in both universe but on different time but you might have missed/ignored it.